# Deserializing Variant JSON Types

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON Converter to deserialize some JSON text, but I have a slight problem, this is that sometimes I get an array of objects returned to me from a web service, and other times it's just a single object, let me give you an example of what I mean:

```
{
   "T":{
      "S":"054",
      "T":"8",
      "D":"548"
   }
}
```

One is an array whereas the other is just a single object.

```
{
   "T":[
      {
         "S":"054",
         "T":"8",
         "D":"548"
      },
      {
         "S":"054",
         "T":"8",
         "D":"548"
      },
      {
         "S":"054",
         "T":"8",
         "D":"548"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I try to deserialize this using Newtonsoft, I get an error because it's expecting an array and sometimes receives only a single object, is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the type of you first property like this :

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
if (obj["T"] is JArray)
{
    // hit on second case
}
else
{
    // hit on first case
}
```

After that's, you can deserialize you object on `List<T>` or `T`.

Hope it's help !

EDIT : With your pastebin classes, I have rebuild them and add a Callback on OnDeserialized :

```
class JSONResponse
{
    public Line ROOT;
}

class Line
{
    [JsonProperty("Time")]
    public Timestamp Time { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("S")]
    public List<Station> S { get; set; }
}

class Timestamp
{
    [JsonProperty("@TimeStamp")]
    public string @TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

class Station
{
    [JsonProperty("@Code")]
    public string @Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@N")]
    public string @N { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("P")]
    public List<Platform> P { get; set; }
}

class Platform
{
    [JsonProperty("@N")]
    public string @N { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@Code")]
    public string @Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("T")]
    public JToken T { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (this.T != null)
        {
            if (this.T is JArray)
            {
                this.Trains = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Train>>(this.T.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Train t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Train>(this.T.ToString());
                this.Trains = new List<Train>() { t };
            }
        }
    }
    public List<Train> Trains;
}

class Train
{
    [JsonProperty("@S")]
    public string @S { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@T")]
    public string @T { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@D")]
    public string @D { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@C")]
    public string @C { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@L")]
    public string @L { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@DE")]
    public string @DE { get; set; }
}
```

You will got your trains, on the Platform.Trains property

Comment: The JSON I've posted is a very simple node took from the real JSON which can be found here: http://pastebin.com/A6qfFFS7 The '@T' nodes are the ones which can be either arrays or objects, so the same JSON stream has both, how do I go about this?

Comment: How do you deserialize your JSON ? With C# classes and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>()` ?

Comment: Yep. JSONResponse centralLine = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONResponse>(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc));

Comment: Could you post JSONResponse class ?

Comment: I add a callback on your models and update them :) Let me know if it's good now !

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish you have one object type to deserialize to, one option would be to *transform* the JSON to an array if it is only a single element -- prior to attempting to deserialize.  e.g.

```
// If only a single element, the JSON will not contain an opening bracket.
if (!str.Contains('['))
{
    var index = str.IndexOf("{",1);  // Ignore first brace.
    var lastIndex = str.LastIndexOf('}'); // Find last brace.
    str = str.Substring(0,index-1) + "[" + 
          str.Substring(index, str.Length - index); // Insert bracket.
    str = str.Substring(0, lastIndex) + "]}"; // Insert bracket.
}
```

You could of course optimize the above to a single statement -- but this just gives you an idea of how you could manipulate the string prior to deserialization.

*This also assumes you have no sub arrays inside of your JSON.  Otherwise, you'll get false positives.*

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work on this I believe: http://pastebin.com/A6qfFFS7 Thanks anyway!